# VIM/Python Insert-Mode-Completion Popup Menu

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I would like to create a VIM insert-mode-completion popup menu, preferably directly via the python vim module but also by calling vim commands if necessary. Per my requirements, if this is possible, what do I need to know?

Requirements

- Modify the menu based on input. Either recolor and replace select characters ala easymotion plugin, or completely replace content, possibly resulting in a change of size.
- Customizable navigation bindings, example:

  - j/k for vertical navigation (*partial redraw*)
  - h/l for category navigation/refinement (*full redraw*)
  - others as category/relationship shortcuts (*full*)
  - others as source cycling (*full*)
  - easymotion-style bindings (*partial*)
  - others for related functionality (*none*)
  - optionally, in lieu of the above bindings, a fuzzy filtering mode (capture all input) (*full*)
- Hook to run action when menu is destroyed
- Ability to replace previous word if menu item selected (easily done in normal mode... but, is there a better approach than calling :norm?)

Once again, I need to know if any of this is possible. If so, please provide specific documentation regarding the required capabilities, APIs, or functions. Well, enough to get me started.

If important, I'm not sure of the interface specifics yet but the menu itself may need to be quite large to accommodate the content.

*Edit:*

I haven't tried anything; rather I'm asking what I should read or know to implement the vim-specific functionality I need. All I now have is python code that accepts a sentence and a word in that sentence, determines the POS, lemmatises the word, and provides synonyms.

It should be clear by now this is a vim plugin providing thesaurus-like functionality, augmenting vim's built-in `CTRL_X-CTRL_T` functionality. Unfortunately synonymy is a complicated hierarchy, for example see [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com) or [wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn). Below is a tree of the synonym selection process. To provide useful thesaurus functionality I would need to navigate this tree within the insert-mode-completion popup menu. By automatically inferring the POS the first step can be skipped, and of course it makes sense to initially merge and display all sense synonyms irrespective of relationship. However, to determine the POS I need access to the entire sentence, and I still need to be able to navigate a sense selection menu. I also want to be able to provide scratch buffer detailing word definitions and example sentences for the currently highlighted popup menu entry. Hence the necessity for a hook; to destroy the buffer when the menu is destroyed. All the other keybindings I've described would be conveniences to, for example, filter by relationship, open the informational scratch buffer, or switch POS.

```
POS  Sense      Relationship      Synonym
N -> Sense 1 -> Relationship 1 -> Synonym 1
                                  Synonym 2
                                  ...
                                  Synonym n
             -> Relationship 2 -> Synonym 1
                                  ...
                                  Synonym n
             -> Relationship 3 -> Synonym 1
                                  ...
                                  Synonym n
     Sense 2 -> Relationship 1 -> ...
     Sense 3 -> Relationship 2 -> ...
V -> Sense 1 -> ...
A -> ...
```

Insert completion popup menus are great because they preserve context: surrounding text doesn't change, remains (mostly) visible, and windows aren't resized. I could provide the functionality I need in a separate buffer (such as a unite plugin), however I'd rather not.

*After reading `:h complete-functions`:*

If `refresh="alway"`, `complete-functions` will be re-invoked each time leading text is changed. The purpose is to refine the matches, however this has little meaning for synonym-matching, where the word is already complete and instead will just be replaced. Aside from this, insert-completion popup menus only provide minimal key mappings: `<CTRL-H>`, `CTRL-L>`, `<CTRL-Y>`, `<CTRL-E>`, etc. Additional mappings can be added using `pumvisible()`, however such mappings affect all popup menus, and so would not be applicable. Of course I could use `<expr>` to check a global variable such as `g:popup-menu-is-thesaurus`, but this approach is basically a heap of hacks. For example, to display a new category in the menu, I could do something like:

```
:call Thesaurus#BindKey("h","w:Thesaurus#CategoryUp")
:call Thesaurus#BindKey("i","w:Thesaurus#InsertMode")
```

with:

```
function! Thesaurus#BindKey(key, function)
  inoremap <expr> a:key a:function
endfunction

function! Thesaurus#CategoryUp()
  if !b:popup-menu-is-thesaurus
    return v:char
  let b:thesaurus-category-index -= 1
endfunction

function! Thesaurus#InsertMode()
  if !b:popup-menu-is-thesaurus
    return v:char
  let b:thesaurus-mode = "insert"
endfunction

function! Thesaurus#CompleteFunc(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    ...
  else
    if b:thesaurus-mode = "insert"
      return Thesaurus#FuzzyMatch(base)
    else
      return Thesaurus#Redraw()
    endif
  endif
endfunction

function! Thesaurus#Redraw()
  ...
endfunction
```

* *Obviously I'm not very good with VimL. Also, am I using `v:char` correctly?*

Of course I have no idea how to replace the previous word once an entry is selected, since the only way to enable fuzzy matching is to have `a:base` be empty.

*Edit2:* And how in the world do I get my completion-function triggered, preferably via the standard thesaurus-style completion shortcut, `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T`? I don't want to lose my custom completions (omni and user-defined completion), and since the popup displays in the current buffer, unlike `FuzzyFinder` I can't override omnifunc.

Perhaps the ideal approach would be to have full control of the menu-drawing functionality to build the popup from scratch, and fake a new insert-completion popup menu mode using plugins such as tinymode, tinykeymap or submode.

Comment: What did you read? What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: What kind of completion do you have in mind? Example? Maybe something already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that the insert-mode completion popup menu is for *completing* matches e.g. offering `foobar` and `foomatic` when you type `foo` and trigger completion. **There is no generic insert-mode menu with arbitrary actions, and it's probably a bad idea to implement such.** That said, some plugins (e.g. *FuzzyFinder*) mis-use insert-mode completion menus for a dynamic choice selector (in a scratch buffer, so what get's completed is discarded there).

You'll find the full specification and an example at `:help complete-function`. If that doesn't satisfy you / leaves open questions, that's a sure sign that you're trying to use it for something it wasn't meant for.

> Modify the menu based on input.

With each typed key, your `'completefunc'` will be re-invoked, and it can offer a (reduced) set of matches.

> Customizable navigation bindings

Bad idea. The user should customize this for *all* completions (using `:imap <expr>` with `pumvisible()` conditionals).

> Hook to run action when menu is destroyed

The `CompleteDone` event has been added in recent Vim versions, but usually the only action should be "insert the match", which gets done automatically.

> Ability to replace previous word if menu item selected

On the first invocation of your `'completefunc'`, your function can specify the *base column*, i.e. where the completion matches will start.